# error in CMake Cyclone DDS, cannot find openssl

Tags: cmake, openssl, data-distribution-service

How can i fix this error,
while doing Cmake, it cant find Openssl, im trying to install cycloneDDS in windows

```
rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~
$ cd cyclonedds

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds (master)
$ cd build

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds/build (master)
$ cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/user -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..-- Eclipse version is set to 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong.
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Building without OpenSSL support
-- Feature rusage disabled
-- Feature netstat disabled
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find BISON (missing: BISON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least
  version "3.0.4")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBISON.cmake:306 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/idl/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/rkpsr/cyclonedds/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/rkpsr/cyclonedds/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

rkpsr@Rahul MINGW64 ~/cyclonedds/build (master)
```

I have included Openssl in Path variable as

[Openssl Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQZ5X.png)

[OpenSSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pykew.png)
[Openssl verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rCec.png)

Comment: Have you read the error message? It suggests to set `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` variable to the OpenSSL installation (root) folder. In your case the installation folder of OpenSSL is probably `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64`.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find OpenSSL, true, but that means it simply builds without any features requiring OpenSSL. The error that causes the build to fail is because I can't find "bison", which is one of the prerequisites listed in the [README](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/#building-eclipse-cyclone-dds).

Besides that, MinGW has its own quirks. I know other people have run into some [issues](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/issues/742) building with it, but they seem to have made it through the CMake stage without trouble.

We currently only check that it builds with Visual Studio. In part that is because of limited resources, but in part it is also because you can easily use one built using VS in MinGW, so it is not like it forces you to build *everything* with VS.

Anyway, any patches that make it play nice with MinGW are most welcome.